# Why is chatGPT 4 unable to correct a program given its output?

Tags: chatgpt, prompt

Recently I used chatGPT 4 to write a small project in Perl which involved reading of an exam file (multiple choice), comparing it to a master exam file, and scoring the student exam including fraud detection and statistics.

chatGPT did a great job of providing low-level code such as regex for pattern matching.

However, chatGPT failed miserably when asked for the program logic of a larger task such as reading the whole exam file and categorizing it into questions, answers, and hints.

What I found stunning was that it got the program logic about 80% correct.

However, even when giving it the whole output it seemed unable to adjust the code and sometimes even made it worse. It was like chatGPT hit a roadblock.

Why is chatGPT unable to refine its code even when prompted with the output and specific instructions on how the output should look vs. what it looks like now?